# Enviar Notificaciones Push si esta logeado OneSignal

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación en Android en la que estoy implementando notificaciones push con OneSignal, hice toda la configuración del GCM y OneSignal para poder enviar notificaciones usando la siguiente linea en mi `MainActivity` dentro del `onCreate`

`OneSignal.startInit(this).init();`

Asi como esta funciona y envía notificaciones al instalar la aplicación, pero quisiera que solo envie notificaciones cuando el usuario este logeado y una vez logeado le lleguen las notificaciones y al cerrar sesión que no le lleguen las notificaciones y este en cola hasta que inicie sesión.

Gracias

Comment: Creo que debes hacer uso de los tokens, yo ando en esa también, podrías decirme de que tutorial te guiaste para poder hacer lo mismo con mi aplicacion estoy haciéndolo con ionic, con que lo haces tu??

Comment: @Pedro Miguel Pimienta Morales estoy usando tokens y webservice y mi aplicación lo estoy haciendo en android nativo y en cuanto a un tutorial si te refieres a como implementar notificaciones push me he guiado de la documentación.

Comment: Pero estas usando GCM o FCM, por que segun estoy leyendo, GMC al menos para proyectos nuevos, no esta funcionando, te guiaste de la documentacion que ponen ellos mismo en oneSignal dependiendo de la plataforma?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales hola donde viste que "GMC al menos para proyectos nuevos, no esta funcionando"? lo pregunto porque al menos lo que tenemos funciona pero han salido algunos issues algo extraños =(

Comment: @Elenasys ya te muestro espera

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales gracias Pedro me interesa mucho esa información!

Comment: @Elenasys en la misma pagina de GCM aparece este mensaje **Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.**

Comment: @Elenasys mira aqui este enlace, en la misma pagina recomiendadan [migrar](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq)

Comment: y un par de enlaces mas 

1. [uno](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/issues/228)
2. [dos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452463/fcm-vs-gcm-why-we-need-to-migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm)

Perdon a @Santiago por llenarle esto de muchos enlaces, espero respuesta, acerca de que si te basaste en la documentacion oficial de oneSignal

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Muchas gracias por la información, en la página lei que se recomienda realizarlo, pero al parecer lo mejor es hacerlo cuanto antes, por ejemplo en ocasiones las Push Notifications con GCM se envian correctamente pero no se reciben por alguna razón desconocida, creo que se debe cambiar cuanto antes a FCM, saludos!

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales efectivamente me base en la doc oficial de OneSignal para Android, no se si sera casi lo mismo para otros tipos de plataforma en tu caso usas Ionic. En cuanto a GCM o FCM uso el GCM, a mi tambien me saltaba la advertencia pero use el GCM y me las arregle para seguir los pasos de las documentacion oficial de antes y no tengo problemas.

Comment: @Santiago voy a probar lo mismo, a ver si puedo hacerlo, lastima que se me daño el telefono

Comment: como estas amigo Santiago, estoy aprendiendo a utilizar las notificaciones push de FCM pero cuando cierro sesion en mi app aun me siguen llegando las notificaciones, creo que es un problema parecido al que tu presentabas si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradeceria, saludos.